# jQuery with Jsonp

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

I use jQuery to get jsonp from a url.

this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://ws.walla.co.il/tem/?a=weather&callback=parseJson?callback=?',
        type: "GET",
        data: JSON,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: "localJsonpCallback"
    });

    function localJsonpCallback(json) {
        if (!json.Error) {
            console.dir(json);
        } else {
            alert(json.Message);
        }
    }
});
```

I get the following json:

```
parseJson({"cities":[{"id":"402","name":"\u05ea\u05dc 
\u05d0\u05d1\u05d9\u05d1",\"url":"\/?
..............}]});
```

i am new to jsonp and i get the following error:

SCRIPT5009: 'parseJson' is undefined

do i need to create callback named parseJson and how i do that.

thanks, shahar.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the target resource is always expecting the callback's name as `parseJson` and also you have 2 `callback` in the url. Also make sure that the callback in the global scope.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://ws.walla.co.il/tem/?a=weather',
        type: "GET",
        data: JSON,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: "localJsonpCallback"
    });
});

function parseJson(json) {
    if (!json.Error) {
        console.dir(json);
    } else {
        alert(json.Message);
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5NC2L/)